# Uninstall applications in the installation and deployment process

Tags: c#, uninstallation, setup-project, windows-installer

I’m creating an application, and I require that in the installation process the application uninstall some others installed programs, So what I have done first is create a console application that uninstall the programs and until there works, I add this console application as a custom actions in the setup and built the solution, but in the installation time the uninstaller does not work.

Sorry for my bad English :).

I use the following code, for uninstall.

```
       string UninstallCommandString = "/x {0} /qn";
        Process process = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;

        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        startInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = string.Format(UninstallCommandString, "{CCB85747-267D-45C6-AC32-7979ADFCD2D8}");
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();

        string UninstallCommandString2 = "/x {0} /qn";
        Process process2 = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo2 = new ProcessStartInfo();
        process2.StartInfo = startInfo2;

        startInfo2.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo2.RedirectStandardError = true;

        startInfo2.FileName = "msiexec.exe";
        startInfo2.Arguments = string.Format(UninstallCommandString2, "{7A8A8C03-6BEA-45B4-BAD9-EBC5790A037A}");
        process2.Start();
        process2.WaitForExit();


        string UninstallCommandString3 = "/x {0} /qn";
        Process process3 = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo3 = new ProcessStartInfo();
        process3.StartInfo = startInfo3;

        startInfo3.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo3.RedirectStandardError = true;

        startInfo3.FileName = "msiexec.exe";
        startInfo3.Arguments = string.Format(UninstallCommandString3, "{6AFDD6D0-3F33-45F0-B058-677F2080AE22}");
        process3.Start();
        process3.WaitForExit();

        string UninstallCommandString4 = "/x {0} /qn";
        Process process4 = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo4 = new ProcessStartInfo();
        process4.StartInfo = startInfo4;

        startInfo4.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo4.RedirectStandardError = true;

        startInfo4.FileName = "msiexec.exe";
        startInfo4.Arguments = string.Format(UninstallCommandString4, "{ACC5E4C6-B4D2-4227-B577-95D511C05A6E}");
        process4.Start();
        process4.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do an install or uninstall from a custom action, and that applies especially to VS setup projects. Only one MSI operation is allowed at a time.

Normally you'd do this with a major upgrade, that's RemovePreviousVersions in a VS setup project, but VS doesn't support anything other than upgrading your setup's current UpgradeCode. Another tool (like Wix) would let you list a bunch of upgrade codes and your install would automatically uninstall the associated products.

So it depends on your workflow requirements. You could zip up your setup into a self-extracting exe that ran your uninstalls, then ran your setup.exe (if you have prerequisites to install) or just installed your MSI. Or you could use an MSI editor tool (such as Orca) to add the UpgradeCodes of those MSI products into the Upgrade table of your MSI, and you've built a RemovePreviousVersions upgrade then it will uninstall them.  Not much of an answer, but you're trying to do something Windows Installer doesn't support (MSI operations from a custom action) and VS doesn't support (upgrades that uninstall other products).

Comment: Yes, Thanks for the reply, I get to that point, I got the solution and is easier than I thought, there are 2 ways to do it.
1. InstallShield Custom actions, After Initialization (before Dialog): If I run my code in this part works perfectly because it does before installation, the problem is that does not work for remote deployment and silent installations.
2. InstallShield Upgrade Paths: Only add .msi program file you want to uninstall, and works perfect!